# Фокусировка экрана на выделенном элементе

Tags: html, ios, safari, javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой в safari на iPhone. Когда на сайте нажимаешь на поле "поиск", появляется клавиатура, можно вводить слова для поиска, но браузер safari переносит экран пользователя на верхний левый угол сайта, поскольку поиск справа - естественно, пользователь теряется.

Подскажите, может, есть какая-то функция, если нажал на элемент - экран переезжает и центрируется на нем. Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться: js или html? Все остальное, думаю, смогу сам написать. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, это стандартная фича мобильных браузеров — увеличивать область с полем ввода. Вопрос в том, почему некорректно определяется положение элемента на странице. Может, это бага браузера. Может, что-то не так с позиционированием самого элемента — попробуйте его поменять.

В любом случае двигать элемент или экран — не выход, это только внесет неразбериху и добавит багов на других устройствах.